# how to send post with FormParams using Angular2

Tags: http, post, angular, form-parameter

client:

I do post in angular2 like this:

```
doSelectMessagesAttributesUrl2(pushRequest : PushRequest) {
    console.info("sending post request");

    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    return this.http
        .post(this.selectMessagesAttributesUrl, JSON.stringify(pushRequest), {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json().data)
        .subscribe(
            data => { },
            err => {  }
        );
}
```

How should i change the request to call the server with FormParam?

server:

```
 @Path("/FeatureGetQueueData")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String runFeatureGetQueueData(@FormParam("queue") MyString paramQueue) throws Exception {

        if (!SupporToolAlert.validateEnvironment(SupporToolConfig.ROW)) {
            return SupporToolAlert.invalidEnvironment();
        }

        String queue = PushQueueConfig.conf().QUEUE.get(paramQueue.value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you combine your form with any model ??

In documentation you can search nice example: [right here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

But if u don't want to create class for your form, u can do something like this:

add each element from form to object, and send this object via http.

something like this:

`form.html`

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
            <label for="status"> Status: </label>
            <input id='status' type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="formModel.operatorStatus" (ngModelChange)="changeFormModel('status', $event)" >
          </div>
</form>
```

now in you component, you need init empty object to contains data from model and implement changeFormModel:

`component.ts`

```
private formModel: any = {};
private changeFormModel(model, event) {
    this.formModel[model] = event;
}
```

now in your http request u can send, formModel, remember to stringify it ;)

Thats not is a perfect solution, but works like charm for me, but in near future i will implement a solution from documentation.

I hope it helped you ;)

Comment: `this.formModel[model] = event` what do this mean?

Comment: set property to object, event contains value from form $event